# Using combined indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have a translation table (MySQL MyISAM) for words (empty right now but will get real big once the words are inserted).

- id_word
- lang_original (the language from the original word) **VARCHAR(2)**
- lang_target (the language from the translated word) **VARCHAR(2)**
- word (the word itself) **VARCHAR(50)**
- translation (the translation) **VARCHAR(50)**

There are only 2 kinds of SELECTs to request information on that table:

## by defining the original language

```
SELECT translation FROM table WHERE lang_original='en' AND lang_target='de' AND word = 'house'
//this will return 'Haus'
```

## by letting the script auto-detect the original language

```
SELECT lang_original,translation FROM table WHERE lang_target='de' AND word = 'house'
//this will return 'en','Haus'
```

Normally i would have these fields with separate indexes:

- id_word
- lang_original
- lang_target
- word

But then, I just read about combined indexes in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114619/mysql-performance-on-6-million-row-table), but I still have some doubts on how to use them.

1. Should I only have 3 indexes, like this?

   - id_word (primary / auto increment)
   - combined: lang_target + word
   - combined: lang_original + lang_target + word
2. Should those combined indexes be UNIQUE or INDEX type? Why?
3. Do I also need to set separated indexes for lang_original, lang_target and word despite the fact that they won't ever be filtered by their own?

**Update 1** fixed = instead of LIKE

Comment: First off, [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) will help point out where improvements can be made.

Comment: Not totally related, but why not considering using http://www.gnu.org/s/gettext/

Comment: `... word LIKE 'house'` Will the word always be the entire word with no wildcards? If so, `LIKE` is unnecessary. Just use `=`.

Comment: @Wiseguy good point, no wildcards here. Switching to =

Comment: does someone know the answer to the 2nd question at the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned above, using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) will show you how queries are executed and which indexes are or *are not* being used.

> 1) Should I only have 3 indexes, like this?
>
> - id_word (primary / auto increment)
> - combined: lang_target + word
> - combined: lang_original + lang_target + word

Having those *composite indexes* would work. There's a lot of overlap between the two composite indexes, so maybe you could find a way to combine them like this:

```
(lang_target, word(10), lang_original)
```

I'd suggest using a sane prefix size for the `word` column so they're a set length (say, 10). The vast majority of words are different within the first 10 chars, so circumstances where it has to read from disk because they're identical through 10 chars will be rare. Prefix length is a balance between index size and execution speed. A bigger prefix will encounter fewer prefix collisions, but it will be a more memory-consuming index. On the other hand, a smaller prefix will save memory but could result in more prefix collisions (thus having to go to disk to make a final determination between a few records). Play with what works for you. Maybe it's 5, maybe it's 15.

> Should those combined indexes be UNIQUE or INDEX type? Why?

If `(lang_target, word, lang_original)` will be a unique combination (which seems to be the case), go ahead and use the `UNIQUE` constraint, *but only if you're not chopping `word` with a prefix* (in which case multiple records with the same partial `word` value might exist). As an index, I think they'll still be functionally equivalent.

> Do I also need to set separated indexes for lang_original, lang_target and word despite the fact that they won't ever be filtered by their own?

Columns in a composite index are used left to right. In `(lang_target, word(10), lang_original)`, the index can be used if you're only querying with a condition on `lang_target`, but if you have a condition on `lang_original`, it couldn't be used unless you're also querying on both `lang_target` and `word`. So, only create other indexes for `word` and/or `lang_original` if you need to be querying *without* a `lang_target` condition. See [this doc page on multiple column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) for more explanation on that.

One other thought:
If your `lang_` columns are always going to be just two characters, make them `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. For a column that size, `VARCHAR` takes an extra byte with each value to specify data length, whereas it's a fixed length with `CHAR`. With millions of records, every byte matters for size and speed.

Comment: Great explanation. I really appreciate it! Im applying changes with all your tips right now.

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out, don't use LIKE unless you need to.

Also, don't use UNIQUE unless the combination really is unique, it looks like there can only be one translation of each word so UNIQUE on (lang_target, word) should be okey but I think performance is better on non unique indexes, think that they don't need the unique check.

You only need one index for those two queries. Don't add more indexes than you need, each index comes with a small cost at insert and update.

(lang_target, word, lang_original). Order is important here as MySQL can use any left part of an index so both a query for *lang_target*, *lang_target + word* or *lang_target + word + lang_original* can use that single index.