# How MySQL client and PDO receive big result with fetch method

Tags: mysql, memory, pdo, client, fetch

If I had a big table (1M rows)

I send a SELECT * FROM table  (without any limit, where ...)

- I use PDO prepared query
- I fetch my result with **only one** PDO::fetch method (not the fetchAll)

What happens at mysql communication layer?

1) Does mysql server send all rows to the mysql client and the mysql client send the first row to PHP? (So a lot of memory is used on the PHP server and the MySQL server)

2) Does mysql client fetch only one row on the network from mysql server? (So a lot of memory is used on the MySQL server only)

(php 5.3.3 and libmysqlclient1.6)

Comment: you use mysql for 1 m rows?

Comment: PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114619/mysql-performance-on-6-million-row-table

Comment: What the problem? I already used mysql with near 1G of rows...

Comment: Zod, your link is out of subject ^^ I m not talking about optimizing a MySQL query (I actually know how to do it, read a query plan ...) but how data are sent to MySQL client with the PDO::Fetch method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the buffering mode you choose and mysql client version. In your case data will be used in the mysql server side.

[Buffered and Unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

Comment: No it won't but the link is really the good one. "Because buffered queries are the default..." so by default, data are sent to client driver to preserve server side Memory usage

Comment: I did, first line: "Queries are using the buffered mode by default. This means that query results are immediately transferred from the MySQL Server to PHP in is then kept in the memory of the PHP process".  That means that data are stored in mysql CLIENT not in the server side...