# Mysql is sucking for large data

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

I have a MySQL database with around 30gb data. Some of the tables contain over 40 million rows. Ｉam using InnoDB. I query by only use "select count(*) from table_name" in local PC takes me around 5 minutes. I think it's impossible for me to the joining of the table. I would like to ask would there anything I could do to improve the performance. Or do I need to switch to another database? I never encounter such large data in DB. Please help.

Comment: Indexing, more info here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/how-to-speed-up-queries-on-a-large-220-million-rows-table-9-gig-data

Comment: Also usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114619/mysql-performance-on-6-million-row-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run mysql instances with over 100 million entries, and delivering over 30 million queries per day. So it can be done.

The problems you are experiencing will occur with any other database system if similarly configured.

I can only give you a few tips, if this is mission critical consider hiring a professional to tweak your system.

Basics that you need to look at;

- This size database is best run on a dedicated server with SSD disks, and at least 2 cores;
- Your going to need a lot of RAM in your server, at least your total database size + 20% for other system resources;
- Make sure mysql has been configured with enough memory, 80% of your total RAM. The primary setting that does this will be `innodb_buffer_pool_size`;
- Optimize your queries, and index where needed - this is a fine art but can drastically improve performance, learn to use `EXPLAIN ...` on your queries.

Comment: May I ask do I only need to change the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size?Is that any great help for change other parameter like innodb_log_size?

Comment: You will see the biggest performance increase from innodb_buffer_pool_size. Other settings will help but not us much and require a lot of attention to detail to configure correctly.

Comment: Thx. How large do you set innodb_log_size for the million entries?

Comment: At least as large as the total of your tables, you can quickly sum the results from `SELECT TABLE_NAME, DATA_LENGTH / ( 1024 * 1024 )  FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY DATA_LENGTH DESC;`

Comment: Thx Harvey.May I ask how you fix import large data .sql file performance into mysql? I use big dump currently, but I spend over 2 days to import a 10gb table to the database. The script file size is around 4 gb. Could you advise how I could import the data faster? I increase the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1024M, but seems still very slow.

Comment: 1024M seems very small for that size database, i would expect at least 10G, or more.

Comment: For improved import have a look at bulk data loading using `OUTFILE` to export and `INFILE` to import; this [gist](https://gist.github.com/yevrah/b67886bdb4dad94cb709/#file-new_file0) may help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94775/discussion-between-harvey-and-user1386463).

Comment: @harvey what do you mean "...at least your total database size + 20% for other system resources"?

Comment: @TokyoToo Your server should have enough memory to load the database and for other user and system processes. For a large database 80% for db, and 20% for system is a good rule of thumb

Comment: @harvey What I mean is... what do you mean db size? You mean size of big data i.e. 100GB or 5PB? So if db is 1PB how much memory do we allocate?

Comment: @TokyoToo I think once you start getting outside of normal RAM ranges you need to start considering alternatives such as high performance SSD.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL InnoDB tables do not keep a count of rows, thus `SELECT COUNT(*)` can be slow.  It's not an indication of how other queries might perform, but it is an indication of how slow a full table scan might be.  Five minutes is really bad for just 40 million rows and might indicate a serious problem with your database or disk.

Here is [a performance blog on the subject](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/).  Also [see this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10976885/14660).

Comment: If this is the case, do I need to switch from innodb to myisam?

Comment: @user1386463 No, MyISAM is inferior to InnoDB in almost every way. You need to make sure your tables are properly indexed. This is a topic too big for me to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter the large date size problem before and hope my experience is useful for you.

first, your need create index for your table, but which kind of index should be used depending on your query logic.

after indexing, if the query is still slow, you'd better divide the data into a hierarchy, for example, source tables, middle tables and report tables. the report table just store some final data and the query will be fast, also create index for it.

third, try to use something like memsql if above mentioned can not meet your require.

besides, learn some command like :

```
set profiling = 1
do some slow query 
show profiles;
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY N;
```

Comment: Thx. Do you mean the final data table is similar to the materialized view in oracle? Is the final data table get the real time data?

Comment: yes, final data just save the processed data for simple query, just like materialized view. technically , it is not real time, because you need process data in source table or middle tables to get the final data. the delay equal to the processing time.