# MySQL - Will updating the primary "id" column improve successive searches? How to do it?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table, something like:

```
table 1

row_id  |  val1  |  val2  |  ...
---------------------------------
   0    |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
   1    |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
   2    |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
   3    |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
```

And so on.

The column `row_id` is:

```
primary key
not-null
auto increment
```

The same value(s) can appear in `val1` and `val2` in multiple rows. For instance:

```
row_id  |  val1  |  val2  |  ...
---------------------------------
   0    |  'one' |  'aaa' |  ...
   1    |  'one' |  'bbb' |  ...
   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
   400  |  'one' |  'ccc' |  ...
   401  |  'one' |  'ddd' |  ...
   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
```

One of the most common queries given to it is:

```
SELECT row_id, val1, val2, etc... 
WHERE val1=? AND val2=? 
ORDER BY row_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The table can get quite long. In the case above, the `row_id=400` row could have 1M rows after it, or more. It isn't a huge amount, but it's enough.

To help improve the efficiency of the search, I would like to change the `row_id` value to the next available id, so that it is closer to the end of the table (and thus, closer to the start of the search). Something like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET r_id=(next_available_...), val3=?, val4=?, etc... 
WHERE val1=? AND val2=? 
ORDER BY r_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

For example, in the case laid-out above, if the next available `row_id` is `22,362`, and my `UPDATE` was for `val1='one'` and `val2='ddd'`, the outcome would be:

```
row_id  |  val1  |  val2  |  ...
---------------------------------
   0    |  'one' |  'aaa' |  ...
   1    |  'one' |  'bbb' |  ...
   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
   400  |  'one' |  'ccc' |  ...
   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
 22,362 |  'one' |  'ddd' |  ...
   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
```

But! Maybe I don't need to?

In most cases, the table will only be hundreds, or thousands of entries long. No big deal. In a few outlier cases, it could be multiple millions. For those tables, would the difference in performance justify *bumping* the `row_id` up? I will do my best to have `val1` and `val2` in the [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114619/mysql-performance-on-6-million-row-table), but things can't always be rainbows and ice-cream.

How can I auto-update the `row_id` value? Or, do I even need to?

Note: This is an InnoDB table, and there could *potentially* be thousands of simultaneous operations going on, from different users all over - `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` and so on. Operations are currently handled with PHP `PDO` operations.

Comment: sounds like a real bad plan

Comment: @Dagon yeah, that's my concern right now. I'm sure it can be done, and done neatly (opposed to multiple queries to gather the next id and then update it), but it's also a pros/cons type of thing, where I'm unsure if it's even worth the trouble.

Comment: Having the id as auto increment would not give you the last id? I know that if you delete records ids can get confusing, but I'm not sure it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are over-thinking (or possibly misunderstanding) the primary key index - as long as it's a auto-incremented integer, that should be fine and regardless of rainbows and ice-cream, your best gains are going to be optimizing the index of the columns you are searching on (val1 and val2). If that doesn't do it, you may want to re-think the data model.

Comment: Sounds about right. And it likely is a misunderstanding, particularly about the index of the columns I'm searching on.

Comment: Text searches in particular can be tricky to optimize and MySql may or may not be the best tool for it, depending on the data.

Comment: Yeah. One of the columns is an `INT(2)` type, but the other is `VARCHAR(60)`. The project is mostly proof of concept, and will likely be ported to a more robust and better-suited language/database combination than PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Giving you the answer. And re-wording the question title to account for the "yes/no" portion of the question, that negates the "how to get the next id..." bit. On account of the best answer not answering that part ;). Good enough for me though!